# Will the stack memory out of block in function be reuse

Tags: objective-c, c, stack

For example：

```
void test(bool aFlag)
{
  if(aFlag)
  {
     int temp =1;
     //do something
  }
  else
  {
     int temp =2;
     //do something
  }

  int aaaa =0;
}
```

when out of if/else block, the memory of temp is no longer use,
will aaaa  reuse the memory of temp? if will  ,when and in what condition?
or will the address of 'temp'  be override later in the function.

Comment: Assuming Objective C has the same memory model as C for PODs, there is no guarantee that it will be the same address. In practice however, yes, `temp`, `temp`, and `aaaa` will be the same address. If you really want to know, just `NSLog("%p", &temp);` and for `aaaa`.

Answer (score 0):

This is up to the compiler. The language doesn't guarantee anything about where variables are stored. However, it would generally make sense for the compiler to generate code like that, yes.

Comment: Yes,It is up to the compiler;
but i want to know in what condition will the compiler generate code like that , which optimization level?
in other word,I want temp and aaaa have the same address,or have their address overlap.

Answer (score 0):

If it is c, then you can't create variables after code. So, I assume aaaa and temp would have different address, especially in debug mode (and they do have). But in release compiler will optimize code, and you can't predict behaviour (there is also branch prediction, and vectorization, and other cpu features, and it can use registers instead of local variables and so on). Use volatile to make them different and declare them at top of function.
Usually, when you enter function it allocate space for local variables and local storage, so

```
aaa is like dword ptr [aaaa],0
temp 1 is like dword ptr [ebp-14h],1  
temp 2 is like dword ptr [ebp-20h],2
```